# Rubbish data when trying to pass numpy array to C++ shared library using ctypes

Tags: c++, python-3.x, numpy, ctypes

I have read a couple of different posts about this but I still not quite figure out how to make it work yet.
Here's my python side:

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer
import numpy as np

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./build/libskel.so")
fun = lib.cfun
fun.restype = None
fun.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_float),
                ctypes.c_size_t,
                ndpointer(ctypes.c_float)]

indata = np.ones((5,6), dtype=np.float32)
outdata = np.empty((5,6), dtype=np.float32)
fun(indata, indata.size, outdata)
print(outdata)
```

And here's my c++ function:

```
extern "C" {

  void cfun(const double *indatav, size_t size, double *outdatav) 
  {
      std::cout << "Size: " << size << "\n";
      size_t i;
      for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      {
          // std::cout << "indatav[i]: " << i << "\n";
          outdatav[i] = indatav[i] * 2.0;
          std::cout << "indatav[i]: " << indatav[i] << ", outdatav[i]: " << outdatav[i] << "\n";
      }
  }

}
```

Now, the output of this python code when I ran it is as follow:

```
Size: 30
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 0.0078125, outdatav[i]: 0.015625
indatav[i]: 3.16696e-321, outdatav[i]: 6.33392e-321
indatav[i]: 4.94066e-324, outdatav[i]: 9.88131e-324
indatav[i]: 5.07566e-317, outdatav[i]: 1.01513e-316
indatav[i]: 2.92487e-321, outdatav[i]: 5.84974e-321
indatav[i]: -nan, outdatav[i]: -nan
indatav[i]: 6.32394e-191, outdatav[i]: 1.26479e-190
indatav[i]: 4.96982e-297, outdatav[i]: 9.93965e-297
indatav[i]: 2.58227e-306, outdatav[i]: 5.16455e-306
indatav[i]: 7.26551e-292, outdatav[i]: 1.4531e-291
indatav[i]: 3.38518e-306, outdatav[i]: 6.77036e-306
indatav[i]: 2.15385e-282, outdatav[i]: 4.30769e-282
indatav[i]: 1.41034e-277, outdatav[i]: 2.82067e-277
indatav[i]: 4.59739e-287, outdatav[i]: 9.19478e-287
indatav[i]: 3.01588e-282, outdatav[i]: 6.03175e-282
indatav[i]: 7.02093e-292, outdatav[i]: 1.40419e-291
[[1.    1.125 1.    1.125 1.    1.125]
 [1.    1.125 1.    1.125 1.    1.125]
 [1.    1.125 1.    1.125 1.    1.125]
 [1.    1.125 1.    1.125 1.    1.125]
 [1.    1.125 1.    1.125 1.    1.125]]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have a feeling that I don't understand my C function as much as I thought (I'm a beginner). If you guys could point out where I went wrong, that would be great!

Comment: Is it intentional that you are passing a `float` from python, but expecting a `double` in c?

Comment: Make sure that, what you are passing from python is what you expect in C. Often there are language-defined rules you have to follow (stack order, naming, types etc).

Comment: @FrederikJuul This is the most shameful question I have ever made. Works now!

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That's what programming in Python would make you.

Comment: Great to hear! :)